# Which of those ways of using Thread class is correct? Thread t = new Thread() or Thread t = new Thread(new Class())?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I've seen 2 ways of using a Thread class:

```
// 1
public class Main extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("abc");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Main()); 
        t.start();

    }
}

// 2
class Main2 extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("abc");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Main2 m = new Main2();
        m.start();

    }
}
```

What are the differences between those 2?

Which way is correct?

Comment: I mean, neither is the way threading happens typically in modern Java; you use Executors.

Answer (score 1):

1 is possible, but superfluous. It works because `Main` implicitly implements [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) since it extends [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html). We would use 1 if `Main` would only `implements Runnable`, but not `extends Thread`.

The "correct" approach is 2.

Comment: what will be better 2 or implements runnable?

Comment: There is no "better" here. It is a matter of personal choice and context.